# No sound Dummy output

Tags: sound

I am new IN USING lINUX and after the installation  I cannot get Ubuntu to see the Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2) with a result of no sound 'Dummy Output'

Thank you for your help and as mentioned I am new using Linux :

```
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 
OS Type 64-bit 
Gnome version 42.9 
Windowing System Wayland 


stargate@stargate-F15-Plus:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04 
Codename: jammy
stargate@stargate-F15-Plus:~$ uname -r
5.19.0-50-generic
stargate@stargate-F15-Plus:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* #
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Jammy Jellyfish - Release amd64 (20230223)]/ jammy main restricted
```

Thank you very much

Any help please I have tried everything

Thank you

Comment: Hi Guiverc,
Thank you for your help and as mentioned I am new using Linux :
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
OS Type 64-bit
Gnome version 42.9
Windowing System Wayland

stargate@stargate-F15-Plus:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
stargate@stargate-F15-Plus:~$ uname -r
5.19.0-50-generic

stargate@stargate-F15-Plus:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20230223)]/ jammy main restricted

Thank you very much